# Как выполнить сравнение переменной в отдельной функции?

Tags: php, функции

В одной функции у меня идет перебор массива.

В переменную $wD каждый раз попадает разное направление ветра.
нужно выполнить перевод на русский внутри цикла, не тащить сравнение в каждой итерации, вынес это действие в отдельную функцию но постоянно происходит ошибка подскажите, что делаю не так? Как исправить?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=8; $i++) {
    $wD = $item->windDirection['name'];
    $ruwD = function wd();
}
function wd(){
    switch ($wD) {
        case 'East':$wD='В';break;
        case 'East-southeast':$wD='ВЮВ';break;
        case 'East-northeast':$wD='ВСВ';break;
        case 'SouthEast':$wD='ЮВ';break;
        case 'South-southeast':$wD='ЮЮВ';break;
        case 'Southwest':$wD='ЮЗ';break;
        case 'South':$wD='Ю';break;
        case 'South-southwest':$wD='ЮЮЗ';break;
        case 'West-southwest':$wD='ЗЮЗ';break;
        case 'West-northwest':$wD='ЗСЗ';break;
        case 'West':$wD='З';break;
        case 'Northwest':$wD='СЗ';break;
        case 'North':$wD='С';break;
        case 'NorthEast':$wD='СВ';  break;
        case 'North-northwest':$wD='ССЗ';break;
        case 'North-northeast':$wD='ССВ';break;
    }
    return $wD;
};
```

Ответ внизу помог, но попробовал воспользоваться именно вторым способом то есть, перевести значения переменной через `array_key_exists`.

в переменную `$test` попадают русскоязычные словосочетания, если в массиве встречаются совпадения, то для примера заменю на цифры, иначе возвращаю, текущее значение. Так вот несмотря на то что в `$test` действительно попадают словосочетания из массива, замены на цифру не произошло, что тут не так??

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++) {
    $symbol = test($item->symbol['name']);
};
function test ($test){
    $world_sides=array(
        'слегка облачно' => 1,
        'облачно' => 2,
        'легкий дождь' => 3,
        'небольшой снегопад' => 4,
        'снегопад' => 5,
    );
    if (array_key_exists($test, $world_sides)){
        return $world_sides[$test];       
    }
    return $test;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php
function wd($wd){...} и вызов $ruwD = wd($wD);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции нужно передать переменную, которая будет использоваться внутри этой функции. Это отсылает вас к вопросу [области видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=8; $i++) {
        $wD = $item->windDirection['name'];
        $ruwD = function wd($wD);
    }
    function wd($wD){
        switch ($wD) {
            case 'East':$wD='В';break;
            case 'East-southeast':$wD='ВЮВ';break;
            case 'East-northeast':$wD='ВСВ';break;
            case 'SouthEast':$wD='ЮВ';break;
            case 'South-southeast':$wD='ЮЮВ';break;
            case 'Southwest':$wD='ЮЗ';break;
            case 'South':$wD='Ю';break;
            case 'South-southwest':$wD='ЮЮЗ';break;
            case 'West-southwest':$wD='ЗЮЗ';break;
            case 'West-northwest':$wD='ЗСЗ';break;
            case 'West':$wD='З';break;
            case 'Northwest':$wD='СЗ';break;
            case 'North':$wD='С';break;
            case 'NorthEast':$wD='СВ';  break;
            case 'North-northwest':$wD='ССЗ';break;
            case 'North-northeast':$wD='ССВ';break;
        }

        return $wD;
    };
```

А вообще можно всё сократить до вот такого варианта. Вместо больших конструкций-условий проще сделать с помощью массива. Мы просто ищем в массиве значение с нужным ключём и возвращаем значение. Массив я тут не заполнял полностью - нудная работа.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=8; $i++) {
    $ruwD = function wd(trim($item->windDirection['name']));
}

function wd($wD)
{
    $world_sides=array(
        'East' => 'В',
        'East-southeast' => 'ВЮВ',
        //остальные стороны света
    );

    if (array_key_exists($wD, $world_sides)){
        return $world_sides[$wD];       
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: попробовал воспользоваться вторым способом из вашего ответа, не помогло, подробности уточнил в вопросе

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Что у вас не работает. Всё хорошо ведь - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3abe1988cde2b67be0e4812e8d0735cb72b93a5 Нажмите на копку, чтобы выполнить код по ссылке

Comment: Если не происходит замена из массива, значит то значение, что вы передали в `$test` не совпало ни с одним в массиве `$world_sides`. Когда будете передавать значения функции, делайте `trim()` - удалит все пробелы по краям лишние - возможно в этом дело. Ответ дополнил - дописал trim

Comment: trim() помог, спасибо,